# Magento: Reprocessing Orders that were made in Authorize.net TEST mode

Tags: magento, authorize.net

We have a client that didn't turn off TEST mode on authorize.net when their Magento site went live. Real customers have placed orders thinking that their credit cards went through. Authorize.net is set on authorize and capture mode.

Is there anyway to reprocess those orders with TEST mode turned off?

Comment: Yikes, sounds like you'll have to have the company contact the customers for payment details again.  Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

The Authorize.net module does not save card data so you cannot resubmit payment requests. You'll have to explain directly to Authorize.net and ask what they can do, although I expect they'll be reluctant.

Comment: so authorize.net saves all the information even though it didn't process it?

Comment: From what I've seen there are two types of debugging with authorize, one is to put the account into test mode and the other is to use a separate test server. On at least one of them the orders are stored on authnet's servers allowing you to inspect them which proves records are kept there. I've only briefly played with it on a past job.